# How does one create a good database schema that takes data versioning into account?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

We are creating a web app with tables not unlike excel.

Sometimes the user might wanna freeze the tables with the current values. This is not something that happens all the time, so some, but not all of the values, might have been updated since the last freeze. After freezing a couple of different versions the user will be able to swap between them. If a historical version is chosen it is loaded into the current table.

We have come up with a schema for this:

This is the current table (with less columns than intended):

| account_id (PK) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 150 |

And the historical would look like this (with less columns than intended):

| account_id (CPK) | value | version (CPK) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 150 | 0 |

The idea is that the first freeze always saves everything. This is reflected in the historical table as is.

We might change id = 0 to 150. Then the next version would only update that one value.

Now the historical table would look like this:

| account_id (CPK) | value | version (CPK) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 150 | 0 |
| 0 | 150 | 1 |

The idea is to look up each row/account_id in the current table, find the newest version and see if this value has changed - if so, it is updated, and thus saved in the table with a new version number.

Likewise, finding the given version of the historical table requires the same operation of looking up rows with the corresponding account_ids and version number, compare, return them if they have changed.

Is this a sensible way to go about this? Or would it be better to just save the whole current table for each freeze? Both saving and retrieving the data would be much easier but the amount of data saved would also increase greatly.

Any comment appreciated.

Searching stack overflow - didn't find anything similar.

Comment: Why not just add a column `valid` with a type of `tstzrange` that shows when the row is valid. Don't create a "history table", but leave all rows in the original table. Current rows have a `valid` with an open end. Then you can always query the state of the table at any given time.

Comment: We went with a single table with a valid column. Thx!